# BigQuery coud not parse into datetime from a csv file

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

While loading data into bigquery, I provided my own schema to avoid confusions with data types. Even now BQ is unable to load values from a datetime format. Although they are quite straight forward as: '1/9/2014 5:26' Here is the full error message:

Could not parse '1/9/2014 5:26' [image]

I thought it might be because of some bad values but have checked the column through and there had been no bad vaules. And it is giving the error on the very first one so it is unable to parse that value without doubt. Notably the values are able to be parsed as string type but not just as the date or datetime types.

Comment: Did you try loading as strings, and parsing in BigQuery later? An example of your data  could be useful o reproduce the issue. Also remember the  [required format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#timestamps)

Comment: @EnriqueZetina the example is given in question: with phrase: Could not parse '1/9/2014 5:26'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load it as a string, use PARSE_DATE, and write it out as new table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  dataset.new_table AS 
SELECT
   *,
   PARSE_DATE("%m/%d/%y %h:%M", str_col) AS date
FROM
   dataset.loaded_table
```

Comment: Thats nice way but wondering why it does not parse it by default. Is there some format requirement for the datetime type?

Comment: Your data could originated in the UK where 06/03/2002 would be March 6 or it could have originated in the US where 06/03/2020 is June 3.  How is BigQuery to reliably know? By specifying the format, you are clarifying this whether is MM/DD or DD/MM, among other things. If your dates had been in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 where there is no such ambiguity, then BigQuery would have parsed it automatically.